# How to pass from array to vector - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm new in c++ programming and I'm trying to understand better the differences between array and vector. In my program I've got a class Graph with some arrays as private members. The class has a method that use these arrays to implement the Prim's algorithm for minimum spanning tree. I took the algorithm from [this page](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithms-set-5-prims-minimum-spanning-tree-mst-2/) and changed it for my program.

I am now asked to use vectors instead of arrays so I would like to know:

How many things do I really have to change? The declaration and the constructors, ok. But the cycles, the initializations. Do I have to change everything? The program works anyway. Is it so important to use vector's function?

Comment: Show us some code and indicate which array should be converted to a vector.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code. I would change the declarations first and see how it goes from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at the code at your link above and spotted quite a few places where STL vectors can be used rather than the arrays that are defined.

For example, below is an example of how to replace a couple of the arrays with vectors, and then initialize their values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

// Number of vertices in the graph
static const int V = 5;

int main()
{
    // Rather than use:
    // int key[V];
    // bool mstSet[V];

    // You could setup STL vector containers:
    std::vector<int> key;
    std::vector<bool> mstSet;

    // Next, initialize:
    for (size_t i = 0; i < V; i++) {
        key.push_back(INT_MAX);
        mstSet.push_back(false);
        std::cout << key[i] << "; " << mstSet[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `<limits.h>` is C, the C++ equivalent is `<limits>`. Don't use `#define`s, use `const`. Avoid other C libraries like `stdio`. Avoid `using namespace std`

Comment: @Manu343726, your exactly right. I cleaned up the code to better illustrate good C++ practice. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with current implementation but you would like to experiment with vectors you could populate vector with array data this way:

`vec.assign(arr, arr + arr_size);`

Comment: This worked! This is the so-called iterator construction a vector from arrays - [the iterator constructor can also be used to construct from arrays](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

It should be very simple to switch from arrays to a `vector`.  You could initialise the `vector` with the size of your array and fill it with `0` elements:

```
vector<YourType> v(size_of_array, YourType(0));
```

and then use `v` more or less as you used your array, i.e.:

```
v[x] = YourType(y);
// ....
f(v[z]);
```

*etc*